# Homeomorphism between circle and ellipse

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that the circle  represented by $x^2+y^2=1$ is homeomorphic to the ellipse $x^2/4+y^2=1$
They are both subsets of $R^2$ of course.
I just don’t know what the functions would look like

What is the function taking the circle to the ellipse and vice versa and how to show that it is continuous

Comment: Try $x\to x/2$.

Comment: Are you serious ? The equations are so similar !

Comment: Attention Yves!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *homeomorphism* is a continuous bijective map that has a continous inverse. Thus, you do not only need to prove continuity but additionally that your *inverse* is continuous, too.

As mentioned in the comments, the map $$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} \frac{x}{2} \\ y \end{pmatrix} $$ does the job.

It's clearly bijective and continous. It's hopefully obvious what the inverse is and you can easily check that it is indeed continous, therefore it's a homeomorphism.